# "Wouldn't have been necessary" or "would have been unnecessary?"

Tags: sentence-meaning, modal-verbs, negation

I've already made the decision to stick to "wouldn't have been necessary," but I wanted to double check. For a little more context, the full sentence is as follows:

> She filled the printer with paper, but if [this] had happened then it wouldn't have been necessary.

Comment: What is "this" and what is "it"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Wouldn't have been necessary" is quite correct and a normal-sounding everyday phrase.

"Would have been unnecessary" sounds a little more formal and forceful, perhaps even less polite in some context.